# (ROBLOX) How would I make this repetitive loop cave code work for my mining game?

Tags: loops, lua, roblox

I'm working on a Mining Game on ROBLOX and I had suddenly gotten a really nice idea on how I'd implement fluids into my caves. The way my caves work are through a repetitive loop, using math.noise which would output a value and if that is above the threshold, it would start the loop and eventually, you'd end up with a cave.

However, I'm pretty confused and from lack of experience, I cannot get it to work. I'm trying to figure out WHEN the loop has stopped as blocks are not being placed but I don't believe I'm doing a very good job of that. Please forgive me if you see anything REALLY stupid, because I've just been swapping the pieces around to see how it'd change the result. This would be my first time actually asking a proper question. I would have  asked on the ROBLOX DevForum, but I was removed from it for the dumbest reason and the moderators do not care if you were innocent.

My code is as follows:

```
local module = {}

module.World = workspace.World
module.WorldScale = 6
module.Blocks = game:GetService('ServerStorage').Blocks

module.WorldContainer = module.World:GetChildren()
module.Directions = {
    Vector3.new(0, 1, 0),
    Vector3.new(0, -1, 0),
    Vector3.new(1, 0, 0),
    Vector3.new(-1, 0, 0),
    Vector3.new(0, 0, 1),
    Vector3.new(0, 0, -1),
}

module.RaycastBlockParameters = RaycastParams.new()
module.RaycastBlockParameters.FilterDescendantsInstances = {module.World}
module.RaycastBlockParameters.FilterType = Enum.RaycastFilterType.Include

local function roundVec3WorldScale(Vec3)
    return 
        Vector3.new(
            math.round(Vec3.X),
            math.round(Vec3.Y),
            math.round(Vec3.Z)
        )   
end

local function GetCaveNoiseAtVec3(Vec3 : Vector3)
    return math.noise(Vec3.X/75, Vec3.Y/75, Vec3.Z/75)
end

module.CreateCaveSubroutine = function(OriginBlock : BasePart, SubroutineInfo)
    warn(SubroutineInfo.BlocksGenerated, SubroutineInfo.LastBlocksGenerated)
    module.DestroyBlock(OriginBlock, SubroutineInfo)
end

module.DestroyBlock = function(Block : BasePart, SubroutineInfo)
    local BlockPosition = Block.CFrame.Position
    Block:Destroy()
    --- New Blocks  
    for i, dirPos in pairs(module.Directions) do
        local newPosition = BlockPosition+(dirPos*module.WorldScale)
        if not module.WorldContainer[newPosition] and newPosition.Y <= 0.5 then
            local newBlock = module.Blocks.Part:Clone()
            newBlock.Parent = module.World
            newBlock.Position = newPosition
            module.WorldContainer[newPosition] = newBlock
            local CaveNoise = GetCaveNoiseAtVec3(newPosition)
            local CaveSubroutine = false
            
            if SubroutineInfo then
                SubroutineInfo.LastBlocksGenerated = SubroutineInfo.BlocksGenerated
            end
            
            if CaveNoise > 0.43 then
                if not SubroutineInfo then
                    SubroutineInfo = {
                        SubroutineTable = {},
                        LastBlocksGenerated = 0,
                        BlocksGenerated = 0,
                    }
                end
                table.insert(SubroutineInfo.SubroutineTable, newBlock)
                CaveSubroutine = true
            end
            if CaveSubroutine then
                SubroutineInfo.BlocksGenerated += 1
                module.CreateCaveSubroutine(newBlock, SubroutineInfo)
            end
            
        end
    end
end

return module
```

I tried to track the iterations of the loop, the blocks generated but got no success. It is always a result like 942, 941 in the output console, or if I changed the code a little, it'd just be 942, 942 or 777, 777 for example.

I'm trying to have it as this:

1 0 <---- start
2 1
3 2
3 3 <---- finished